# How do I disable Expander expansion based on a property

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, telerik, expander

I am having an issue with telerik expander IsExpanded bit

- Scenario -

I want if the bound property is False, user should not be able to expand the expander and if the expander was Expanded it should close it self.

- Implementation -

I made a simple style like this --

```
<Style TargetType="telerik:RadExpander">
    <Style.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding CanMultiSelect}" Value="False">
            <Setter Property="IsExpanded" Value="False"></Setter>
            <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="False"></Setter>
        </DataTrigger>
     </Style.Triggers>
 </Style>
```

This style partly works fine, so when canMultiSelect is false, it disables the expander as it should, but if the expander was expanded when property went false, it doesn't closes it self.

Any ideas or other implementations appreciated.

-- Edit

I have tried same with wpf expander but it makes no difference

Comment: Is `IsExpanded` bound on the `Expander`? Do you set initial value?

Comment: there is initial value set to false, but I have tried with or without it, the expanded expander goes diabled but doesn't closes itself

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
<Style TargetType="telerik:RadExpander">
    <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="True">
    <Style.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding CanMultiSelect}" Value="False">
            <Setter Property="IsExpanded" Value="False"></Setter>
            <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="False"></Setter>
        </DataTrigger>
     </Style.Triggers>
 </Style>
```

This means that the default `IsEnabled` will be true and when `CanMultiSelect` is false these are set to false

Comment: nop, no difference, also, I don't want it to expand when canMultiSelect is true, I just want it to go expandable ..

Comment: in that case it might be a bug in the telerik control. From your Xaml what you are expecting should work fine

Comment: yea that's what I think now, lemme try with other expander

Comment: WPF expander works like this .. dunno whats wrong now.

Comment: probably to do with the binding on the telerik control not being two way or something like that

Comment: there is no binding on it ..... <telerik:RadExpander x:Name="MultiSelectExpander" BorderThickness="1" Grid.Row="2">

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to set the value for `IsExpanded` through the setter. Instead, you should create a corresponding property on your `ViewModel` and bind to it:

```
... IsExpanded={Binding IsExpandedPropertyOnViewModel} ...
```

Then, in the setter of `IsExpandedPropertyOnViewModel`, you can implement whatever logic you need and keep the backing field to `false` even if value is `true`.

```
bool _isExpandedPropertyOnViewModel=false;
public bool IsExpandedPropertyOnViewModel{
   get { return _isExpandedPropertyOnViewModel;}
   set
   {
      if(CanMultiSelect)
      {
         _isExpandedPropertyOnViewModel=false;     
      }
      else
         _isExpandedPropertyOnViewModel=value;     
      NotifyPropertyChanged(...);
   }
}
```